# Vertical tabs with Title in the same row as content to maintain height

Tags: jquery, tabs, accordion

I'm trying to figure out how to recreate a tabs/accordion functionality where it seems the Title and content are on the same row thus when clicking the title the row expands to the full height of the content and pushes the following tabs down, keeping their content hidden but still showing the title. It's like a cross between vertical tabs and a slider.

[image: ![slider/tabs combination]

The image above is what I'm working from - when you click each of the headings **Masterclass, Mixer, Academy** This should hide the content leaving only the title and expand the selected row to the full height of the corresponding content.

I'm sure this functionality has a specific name but I can't for the life of me think of it. Even after a few hours of JSfiddle and Codepen searches I'm stil stumped.

I've set up the HTML on JSfiddle [here:](https://jsfiddle.net/Dtorr1981/j4rs0nqf/10/) - The HTML is below.

I'm happy to figure it out myself if I can be pointed in the right direction?

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="row evtabs-section" id="evtabs-1">
                <div class="col-md-6 evtabs-title">
                    <h2>
                        Heading 1
                    </h2>
                    
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 ev-tabs-content">
                    <p>
                        Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui.
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <a class="btn" href="#">View details »</a>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row evtabs-section" id="evtabs-1">
                <div class="col-md-6 evtabs-title">
                    <h2>
                        Heading 2
                    </h2>
                    
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 ev-tabs-content">
                    <p>
                        Tab 2 Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui.
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <a class="btn" href="#">View details »</a>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row evtabs-section" id="evtabs-1">
                <div class="col-md-6 evtabs-title">
                    <h2>
                        Heading 3
                    </h2>
                    
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 ev-tabs-content">
                    <p>
                        Tab 3 Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui.
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <a class="btn" href="#">View details »</a>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thank you in advance for your support and suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to find a solution - I think I was over complicating what was required. My solution is below:

```
<div id="top-event-accordion">
<div class="row ev-accord" id="evtabs-1">
  <div class="col-md-6"><h2>Masterclass </h2></div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
  <div id="ev1">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut ero labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco.Lorem ipsum dolor sit Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco.Lorem ipsum dolor sit 
  </p><p><a class="sppb-btn  sppb-btn-primary sppb-btn-lg sppb-btn-rounded" href="#">LEARN MORE</a></p>
  </div>
  </div>
</div><div class="row ev-accord" id="evtabs-2">
  <div class="col-md-6"><h2>Mixer</h2></div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
  <div id="ev2">
  <p>Maecenas eu arcu tellus. Nulla facilisi. Curabitur in eros eget metus ullamcorper ultrices id nec leo. Maecenas gravida, nibh ut vulputate laoreet, sem turpis ultrices odio, eget pharetra risus ipsum at nunc. Nam quis sapien sollicitudin, rutrum purus id, suscipit nibh.</p><p><a class="sppb-btn  sppb-btn-primary sppb-btn-lg sppb-btn-rounded" href="#">LEARN MORE</a></p>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row ev-accord" id="evtabs-3">
  <div class="col-md-6"><h2>Academy</h2></div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
  <div id="ev3">
  <p>Suspendisse commodo laoreet ante eget rhoncus. Duis a tortor metus. Maecenas metus quam, consequat eget nisi ac, aliquam eleifend tortor. Proin urna metus, pellentesque non suscipit et, pulvinar nec nisl. Aliquam ac elit vehicula, iaculis felis quis, efficitur erat. 
  </p><p><a class="sppb-btn  sppb-btn-primary sppb-btn-lg sppb-btn-rounded" href="#">LEARN MORE</a></p>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The required JS is below:

```
/** Events Top Module Accordion **/


document.getElementById("ev2").style.display='none';
document.getElementById("ev3").style.display='none';


$('#evtabs-1').click(function() {
   $('#ev1').show();
   $('#ev2').hide();   
   $('#ev3').hide();   
});
$('#evtabs-2').click(function() {
   $('#ev1').hide();
   $('#ev2').show();   
   $('#ev3').hide();   
});
$('#evtabs-3').click(function() {
   $('#ev1').hide();
   $('#ev2').hide();   
   $('#ev3').show();   
});
```

Working JSFiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Dtorr1981/2e643xLq/2/)